# PayPal tracking not showing the Receipt ID for certain transactions

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using Website Payments Standard account and I have integrated Add to Cart button and Subscription button in my website. Few payments were made by my clients. But upon downloading my transaction history, I cannot view/retrieve the Receipt ID for certain payments, no matter if it is through Add to Cart or Subscription. Few transactions shows blank field for receipt ID. Can anyone guide me in finding out the problem? Is it anything related to my Website Payments Standard account? Or anything related to my client's account?

Answer (score 0):

The [PayPal IPN variable reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EAB0105Z__id0913D0F0PHO) states the following for the receipt_id parameter.

> Unique ID generated during guest checkout (payment by credit card
>   without logging in).

Sounds to me like you must have some payments coming through via guest checkout and others coming through as actual PayPal payments, so those wouldn't have a receipt_id.

Comment: Thank you! Let me check.